# Regex: Find the last unique sub-string at the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Match

```
condition #1.The last occurrence of a string of characters followed by a comma or white space.
condition #2.The occurrence has to be the end of the string
condition #3.The occurrence has to be a unique sub-string
```

I can't figure out how to apply the 3rd condition into my reg expression

expression:

```
/[\w]{2,30}[\s,](?!.*[\w]{2,30}[\s,])$/g

[\w]{2,30}                    --Any sub-string of characters of length 2 to 30
[\s,]                         --Is white space or comma
(?!.*[\w]{2,30}[\s,])         --Only match the last occurrence
$                             --End of string
```

My expression only covers conditions #1 and #2.

```
#1. The last occurrence of a string of characters followed by a comma or white space.
#2. The occurrence has to be the end of the string.
```

I want my expression to return a match when [\w]{2,30} is unique AND #1 #2 are still valid.

```
//Result
string: 'a, bb, ccc, ccc(space or ,)'
match: 'ccc(space or ,)'

//Expected Results
string: 'a, bb, ccc, ccc(space or ,)'
match: no match

string: 'a, bb, ccc, ccc(space), abc(space or ,)'
match: 'abc(space or ,)'

string: 'a, bb, ccc, ccc(space), abc(space or ,)(any character or white space or ,)'
match: no match
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern you are only matching, but not checking for the same occurrence of the pattern `\w{2,30}` to make sure it is unique.

To do so, you could use a negative lookahead with a capture group and a backreference to make sure that the occurrence at the end is not present earlier in the string.

```
^(?!.*\b(\w{2,30})\b.*\1[,\s]$).*\b(\w{2,30}[,\s])$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that to the right is not

  - `.*\b(\w{2,30})\b` Match the whole line, then a word boundary and capture in **group 1** matching 2-30 word chars followed by a word boundary
  - `.*\1` Match the whole line and then a backreference to capture group 1 to match the same text
  - `[,\s]$` Match either `,` or a whitespace char at the end of the string
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `.*` Match the whole line
- `\b(\w{2,30}[,\s])` A word boundary, match 2-30 word chars followed by either `,` or a whitespace char
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/EZoFeM/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?!.*\b(\w{2,30})\b.*\1[,\s]$).*\b(\w{2,30}[,\s])$/;
[
  "a, bb, ccc, ccc ",
  "a, bb, ccc, ccc , abc ",
  "a, bb, ccc, ccc , abc  "
].forEach(s => {
  console.log(`${regex.test(s)} ---> ${s}`);
})
```

Comment: Ty! I feel your answer is the most complete because it solved the task and you gave a more complete explanation of the the components in your expression.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
\b(\w{2,30})(?<!\b\1\b.*?\b\1\b)[ ,]$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ic2yqI/1)

---

- `\b(\w{2,30})` - A word-boundary followed by a capture group to match a substring of 2-30 word-characters;
- `(?<!\b\1\b.*?\b\1\b)` - Negative lookbehind (zero-width allowed) to test the previously captured substring is not found previously;
- `[ ,]$` - A space or comma before the end-line anchor.

---

```js
const r1 = ['a, bb, ccc, ccc ', 'a, bb, ccc, ccc , abc ', 'a, bb, ccc, ccc , abc  '];
const r2 = r1.map(Re_Extract);

function Re_Extract(str) {
  const s = str.match(/\b(\w{2,30})(?<!\b\1\b.*?\b\1\b)[ ,]$/g);
  if(s) {
    return s[0];
  }
  else {
    return s;
  }
}

console.log(r2);
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply the third condition of matching a unique sub-string, you can use a positive lookahead to ensure that the sub-string is not repeated earlier in the string. Here's an updated regular expression that includes all three conditions:

/(?<=\s|^)[\w]{2,30}\s,/g

Let's break it down:

(?<=\s|^) - Positive lookbehind to ensure that the match is preceded by a whitespace or the beginning of the string.

[\w]{2,30} - Any sub-string of characters of length 2 to 30.

[\s,] - White space or comma.

(?=(?:(?!\1)[\w]{2,30}[\s,])*[\w]{2,30}[\s,]$) - Positive lookahead to ensure that the sub-string is not repeated earlier in the string and it's the last occurrence.

This is achieved using a non-capturing group (?:) with a negative lookahead to check for any previous occurrence of the same sub-string, followed by the same sub-string at the end of the string.

Note that the use of \1 in the negative lookahead refers to the previous captured group, which in this case is the sub-string of characters matched by the previous instance of [\w]{2,30}[\s,].

Comment: \1 returns an error. Here is the link https://regex101.com/r/3K0bkq/1

Comment: (?<=\s|^)[\w]{2,30}[\s,] returns multiple matches. https://regex101.com/r/F2B4TP/1. There should only be one match and it should be at the end of the string.